# Python flask_caching, Generate Unique page Dependent on Passed Cookies

Tags: python, flask, caching, cookies

For my Flask application I currently have the following

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_caching import Cache

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping({'CACHE_TYPE' : 'filesystem', 'CACHE_DIR' : 'CACHED_PAGES'})
cache = Cache(app)

@app.route('/some_url', methods=['GET'])
@cache.cached(timeout=0, query_string=True)
def some_url():
```

If my application returns a few variations of the page, depending on what cookies are set, how can I allow a page to be cached specific to what cookies are set?

I'm supposing that the cache_key, or file name for the cache file should be generated with the inclusion of the passed cookie data.

Can somone provide a code example of how this would work?

Comment: Sounds like you're after the `memoize` function in flask-caching [link](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#memoization). You'd need to parse your cookies somehow before passing them to the function.

Comment: @PGHE I actually read that page before posting the question, but I don't quite get how it can be done. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to cache, but memoization may work for you with smaller methods rather than an entire view.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_caching import Cache

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping({'CACHE_TYPE' : 'filesystem', 'CACHE_DIR' : 'CACHED_PAGES'})
cache = Cache(app)

@cache.memoize(50)
def method_1(cookie_1):
   return cookie_1

@cache.memoize(50)
def method_2(cookie_2):
    return cookie_2


@app.route('/some_url', methods=['GET'])
def some_url():
    result_1 = method_1('a cookie value')
    result_2 = method_1('another cookie value')
    render_template('template.html', result_1=result_1 , result_2=result_2)
```

To cache a view with memoziation you'd have to rely on the url parameters passed into the view function rather than cookies.

Comment: I'm going to try this out

Comment: basically I wish to cache an html page generated from a view, including specific url parameters "/go?option=variablevalue"... I can already do this, but my website also has 4 view tabs which the user can select. When a tab is selected, a cookie is set so later when they visit the page they are automatically returned 1 of the 4 versions of the page.